# How to create a conda environment with specified libraires?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, environment, conda

When creating a new conda environment, some packages are installed by default.

```
> conda create -n newEnv python=3.6

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

     openssl:    1.0.2k-1
     pip:        9.0.1-py36_1
     python:     3.6.1-0 
     ...
     zlib:       1.2.8-3
```

I believe there is a way to specify the default libraries to install when creating a new environment *without having to type all the names after the conda create command*.

Is there any file I can edit so as to specify which are the default libraries to install when creating a new environment with conda?

**Solution :** 
Based on **holdenweb** answer below, you need to add the following line in your .condarc (doesn't exist by default) :

```
create_default_packages:
     - jupyter
     - matplotlib
     - otherLibrary
     ...
```

This is a list of libraries that will be installed when creating a new environment. You can also add libraries directly by using the following command (using *jupyter* as an example)

```
conda config --add create_default_packages jupyter
```

which will append the specified library (here *jupyter*) to the list above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the `create_default_packages` option? You can specify a list of default packages using this directive in your `.condarc` file. It's documented [on this page](https://conda.io/docs/config.html#always-add-packages-by-default-create-default-packages). You can override it with the `--no-default-packages` command-line option.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. I edited my question with your answer and an actual example for sake of completeness.